# XNA Rendering to a Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

So how do I render a texture2d to another one? I'm pretty sure its possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sure is; Check the article here:
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php.

Comment: Not a bad article. But where it says "The last line retrieves the contents of the rendertarget and puts it in our texture!". This seems to be a frequent source of confusion. In XNA 4.0 a `RenderTarget2D` *is* a `Texture2D`. If you want a copy of the data you have to actually copy it out (ie: `GetData`/`SetData`); you can't just cast it to `Texture2D`, because it's still that same render target.

Comment: @Andrew But if you don't need to access to the data, you can treat the render target just like a Texture2D, passing it to SpriteBatch.Draw for example. Just want to make sure that's clarified.

Comment: Of course. I've just seen a couple of people thinking that a the act of casting it to `Texture2D` creates a copy - it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
    Color[] bits = new Color[TextureSource.Width * TextureSource.Height];
    TextureSource.GetData(bits);
    TextureCopy.SetData(bits);
```

If I got what you meant by render right.